# Where does this formula for the product of Gamma Functions come from?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

$$\prod_{r=1}^{n} \Gamma \Big(\frac{r}{n+1}\Big) = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^{n}}{n+1}}$$

I came across the formula at the bottom of the Wikipedia page on specific values of the Gamma function but it was mentioned in passing and a proof is not referenced.

Comment: From the reflection formula $\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$

Comment: Using Gauss' Multiplication Formula?

Comment: What do you mean ? Then $e^{it}-e^{-it}$ and $x^{n+1}-1 = \prod_{m=1}^{n+1} (x-e^{2i \pi m/(n+1)})$

Comment: Not following...

Comment: I completely just see it from the reflection formula now, thanks.

Comment: $\sin(t) = \frac{-e^{-it/2}}{2i}(1-e^{it})$. What are the roots of the degree $n+1$ polynomial $x^{n+1}-1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of relations like this can be derived using the Euler Form of the Gamma Function, which re-writes the gamma function as a limit. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Gamma_Function/Euler_Form).

In this case this is the Gauss Multiplication Formula, whose proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gauss_Multiplication_Formula).